# Polymer - before/after slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to create a before/after image slider similar to before-after.js or cocoen as a custom Polymer Web Component for Rails. However, I'm having some JavaScript issues with my implementation. Some have already been solved during the course of this question. The main remaining problems are:

1. Only the first instance of the component on the page works!
2. The web component's DOM elements are not found by the JS unless
   they are inside `window.onload`, even though the script is included
   at the very end of the .html for the component.

Here are the HTML, JS, and CSS files for the slider:

**image-slider.html**:

```
<dom-module id="image-slider">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="image-slider.css" />
  <template>
    <div id="dual-wrapper" style$="border: [[border]]; 
          border-radius: [[border_radius]]; width: [[width]]; 
          height: [[height]]; margin: [[margin]];">
      <div id="img-snd-wrap">
        <img src$="[[snd]]" class="img-snd">
      </div>
      <div id="img-fst-wrap">
        <img src$="[[fst]]" class="img-fst">
      </div>
      <div class="img-blind" style="width: [[width]]; height: [[height]]"></div>
      <div id="img-transition-slider" style$="height: [[height]];">
        <div id="img-transition-slider-handle" 
        style$="margin-top: calc([[height]]/2 - [[handle_height]]/2); 
        height: [[handle_height]];">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script src="image-slider.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

**image-slider.js**:

```
Polymer({
    is: "image-slider",
    properties: {
        fst: {
            type: String
        },
        snd: {
            type: String
        },
        width: {
            type: String
        },
        height: {
            type: String
        },
        border: {
            type: String,
            value: "none"
        },
        border_radius: {
            type: String,
            value: "0px"
        },
        handle_height: {
            type: String,
            value: "80px"
        }
    },
    attached: function () {
        var slider, first, second, container, x, prev_x, containerWidth;

        slider = this.$['img-transition-slider'];
        console.log(slider);
        first = this.$['img-fst-wrap'];
        second = this.$['img-snd-wrap'];
        container = this.$['dual-wrapper'];
        slider.onmousedown = function(e) {
            document.body.style.cursor = "col-resize";
            containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
            prev_x = x - slider.offsetLeft;
            slider.querySelector("#img-transition-slider-handle").style["background-color"] = '#888';
        };
        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            // X coordinate based on page, not viewport.
            if (e.pageX) { x = e.pageX; }
            // If the object specifically is selected, then move it to 
            // the X/Y coordinates that are always being tracked.
            if(slider) {
                var toReposition = (x - prev_x);
                var newPosition = ((toReposition > containerWidth) ? 
                                        containerWidth - 2
                                    : ((toReposition < 0) ? 
                                        0
                                    :
                                        toReposition
                                    ));
                slider.style["margin-left"] = newPosition + 'px';
                second.style["width"] = newPosition + "px";
                first.style["width"] = (containerWidth - newPosition) + "px";
                first.style["margin-left"] = newPosition + "px";
                first.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style["margin-left"] = (-newPosition) + "px";
            }
        };
        document.onmouseup = function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
            slider.querySelector("#img-transition-slider-handle").style["background-color"] = '#555';
            slider = false;
        };
    }
});
```

**image-slider.css**:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}

#dual-wrapper {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#img-fst-wrap, #img-snd-wrap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-blind {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#img-transition-slider {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#img-transition-slider:hover {
    cursor: col-resize;
}

#img-transition-slider-handle {
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 2px;

    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}
```

Comment: Cool. I should've updated my post as I managed to solve the JS functionality part. Now I'm just having some major troubles making the web component duplicatable.

Comment: attached: function () {
 slider = this.$['image-transition-slider'];
} seems to be setting slider to undefined

Comment: It wasn't. I think we're getting closer. Now the styling's all messed up and the slider for the first n items only affects the last n item. (adding updated code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124074/discussion-between-ian-h-and-supersharp).

Comment: which event callback?

Comment: cool - those are inside now. unable to let go of the slider at this point. updated code once again. should the vars at the top go inside somehow as well?

Comment: Hmm ok. Still no luck with document.onmouseup event causing drag to end (it is being called)

Comment: Yes, mouseup event is supposed to stop the dragging, but the slider bar just keeps following the mouse after it is released. Is document.onmouseup the wrong type of onmouseup?

Comment: it's because you does'nt unregister the onmousemove event anymore

Comment: slider = false isn't enough?

Comment: Now I'm having the opposite problem. Releasing the mouse causes the slider to be undraggable a second time!

Answer (score 1):

If the web component is not duplicable, it is because you use `document.getElementById()` on `id`s  that are themselves duplicated. So only the first (or last) element defined with this `id` will always be returned.

You should use [`this.$.[sub-element's id]`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) to select an element inside the subtree of the Polymer element and add mouse event listener **from inside the Polymer element**, in the [`attached() callback`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners) method:

```
var slider = this.$['image-transition-slider']  
//define the mouse event listeners inside the element
```

where `this` is the reference to the custom element itself.

Comment: Is $ allowed if I can't figure out how to incorporate JQuery?

Comment: @IanH this.$ (from Polymer) has nothing to do with $ (from jQuery)

Comment: Will using the this.$ selector wait for the object to exist? Using pure javascript I was having trouble with the DOM elements for the component not existing when I tried to get them, even though the script is inserted after everything else in the web component.

Comment: if you use it in the attached callback it will be defined for sure

Comment: I still end up getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image-transition-slider' of undefined" if I do that command outside the window.onload